# Dialog close without selecting the value into text fields on on Simulator

Tags: codenameone

I use the dialog to display date range control. On Simulator before selecting the value dialog closes and I'm not able to change or update any value. Please see the code below. Please advise if there is any known issue.

Comment: Which dialog? The picker or the popup? I'm guessing the lightweight picker triggered something here but we'll need an isolated test case

Comment: @Shai...Popup itself closes on selection on the picker.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably related to this line:

```
range.setDisposeWhenPointerOutOfBounds(true);
```

When you start interacting with the Picker popup, it disposes the dialog because the pointer it outside the bounds of the underlying dialog.

I have made a change to Dialog that will be available in the next update on Friday that will fix this issue.

https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/commit/2c5fbfc9ae06e35911b5832441a685724e9739a0